# Regex return match plus string up until next match

Tags: python, regex, python-re

**Goal**: Break text into a list based on a numeric or decimal match that retrieves all text up until, but not including the next match. Language/version: Python 3.8.5 using python re.findall() and I'm open to alternate suggestions.

**Text example** (yes, it's all on one line):

```
 1 Something Interesting here 2 More interesting text 2.1 An example of 2C19 a header 2.3 Another header example 2.4 another interesting header 10.1 header stuff  14 the last interesting 3A4 header
```

**Goal Output**:

```
['1 Something Interesting here',
'2 More interesting text',
'2.1 An example of 2C19 a header',
'2.3 Another header example',
'2.4 another interesting header',
'10.1 header stuff',
'14 the last interesting 3A4 header'
]
```

I can identify *most* of the appropriate integer/decimal starting points using:

`(\d+\.\d+)|([^a-zA-Z]\d\d)|( \d )`

I'm struggling to find a way to return the text between the matches plus the match itself.

To save you some time, [here's my Regex sandbox](https://regex101.com/r/9dwsF6/2)

Thank you kindly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead expressions to match until the next match.

Here is the updated regex ([sandbox](https://regex101.com/r/NoOxWS/2)):

`\b(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b.*?(?=\b(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b|$)`

In python:

```py
regex = r'\b(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b.*?(?=\b(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b|$)'
string = ' 1 Something Interesting here 2 More interesting text 2.1 An example of 2C19 a header 2.3 Another header example 2.4 another interesting header 10.1 header stuff  14 the last interesting 3A4 header'
result = re.findall(regex, string)
```

In this case, `result` will be:

```
>>> result
['1 Something Interesting here ',
 '2 More interesting text ',
 '2.1 An example of 2C19 a header ',
 '2.3 Another header example ',
 '2.4 another interesting header ',
 '10.1 header stuff  ',
 '14 the last interesting 3A4 header']
```

Note that this solution also extracts the spacing at the end. If you don't want this spacing, you can call `strip` on your strings:

```
>>> [ match.strip() for match in result ]
['1 Something Interesting here',
 '2 More interesting text',
 '2.1 An example of 2C19 a header',
 '2.3 Another header example',
 '2.4 another interesting header',
 '10.1 header stuff',
 '14 the last interesting 3A4 header']
```